# Is there any function to assign values in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, arcgis

I am trying to assign values to some rows using pandas dataframe. Is there any function to do this?

Comment: values to whole rows or just exact cells ???

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately, this is a very broad question that might have been better as a search in the pandas docs. Please provide a [mcve] as outlined so that we can be more helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

For a whole column:

```
df = df.assign(column=value)
```

... where `column` is the name of the column.

For a specific column of a specific row:

```
df.at[row, column] = value
```

... where `row` is the index of the row, and `column` is the name of the column.

The later changes the dataframe "in place".

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-add/).

Basically, try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
  
# Creating a dataframe 
# Setting the seed value to re-generate the result. 
np.random.seed(25) 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns =['A', 'B', 'C']) 
  
# np.random.rand(10, 3) has generated a 
# random 2-Dimensional array of shape 10 * 3 
# which is then converted to a dataframe 
  
df
```

You will get something like this:

[image: output]